# Selenium Long Page Load in Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapinghub

I have built a scraper in python 3.6 using selenium and scrapinghub crawlera. I am trying to fetch this car and download its photos. https://www.cars.com/vehicledetail/detail/800885995/overview/ but the page just keep loading for long periods of time. What I am trying to figure out is how can I stop the browser from continuously loading after 4 mins.

I have tried both explicit and implicit wait and none has worked.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver', 
                            desired_capabilities=capabilities, 
                            options=chrome_options)
driver.implicitly_wait(180)
driver.get(url)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the max waiting time for loading with `driver.set_page_load_timeout()`. 
In case the page passes its loading time, the browser will throw a `TimeoutException`. All you need to do is to take care of it

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver', 
                            desired_capabilities=capabilities, 
                            options=chrome_options)

driver.set_page_load_timeout(time_to_wait)
try:
    driver.get(url)
except TimeoutException:
    # Do what you need here
```